# No puedo hacer la conexión de mi proyecto Angular a mi base de datos phpMyAdmin ¿Alguna solución?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Resulta que estoy con una página con Angular y quiero realizar una Conexion con una base de datos hecha con phpMyAdmin.

Esta es la conexión:

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "1234";
    $db = "data_tarjeta";

    $conexion = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

    if($conexion -> connect_errno){
        die ("Conexion Fallida" . $conexion -> connect_errno);
    } else {
        echo "Conectado";
    }
?>
```

Y me sale este error cuando verifico si se realizó la conexión:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\back\conexion.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\back\conexion.php(7): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'data_tarjeta') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\back\conexion.php on line 7

Ya cambié los puertos de Apache y MySQL, cambie la contraseña y aún no he encontrado una solución.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Crea un usuario con contraseña aparte y checa si te puedes conectar.

Comment: Hola y gracias por comentar, lamentablemente probé creando otro usuario con contraseña aparte y me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Y si en lugar de contraseña mandas un string vacío?

Comment: Anteriormente no tenía contraseña y me pasaba lo mismo. Ahora volvi a intentar con un string vacio y pasa lo mismo.